# Able to connect my TWS:Oppo buds to Ubuntu LTS 20.04 BUT they are not being detected as audio devices, they work smooth with my smartphone and windows

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, blueman

Please help, I am unable to watch my university lectures.

[Bluetooth shows my buds are connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yGe3.png)

[Under Sound Settings - input and output devices doesn't detect my bluetooth earbuds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp1tJ.png)

Yesterday, these buds were working just fine, don't know what happened in a span of just 1 day.

I am on it from last 2 hours now, please someone help!

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issues and this is how I fixed it:

1. Open your bluetooth config:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
   ```
2. Find `ControllerMode` and change its value to "bredr" from "dual".
3. Restart you bluetooth driver with

   ```
   sudo etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
   ```
4. Now try to connect your device!

Answer (score 0):

Follow Below commands:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth


sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```